# How can I get the unique values from the Array

Tags: arrays

I still learning about Array but I want to learn how to do this. 
I am looking for the code that will display only the unique values from the array lists, that is "Tom" "Mike" "First"

```
String[] name={
              "Tom","Mike","First","Mike","Tom"
              };
for (int i=0;i<name.length;i++){

}
```

I know we need a loop to go over the index starting from 0. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: which language your working on Java??

Comment: If you want some kind of container with unique elements, what you want is a data structure called Set

Comment: Is any of answers correct? If yes, please mark so the thread is closed

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way:

```
Set<String> uniqueNames = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(name));    
for (String uniqueName : uniqueNames) {
   System.out.println(uniqueName);
}
```

If you really want to loop over the original array, you can remember names that you already displayed (however I would suggest the first example):

```
Set<String> usedNames = new HashSet<>();
for (String aName : name) {
   if (!usedNames.contains(aName)) {
      System.out.println(aName);
      usedNames.add(aName);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, because it sounds homeworky, but if you sort your input array first, you can loop over it and add any element not identical to its predecessor to the output array.  Any identical elements in a sorted array are consecutive.  However, the sort will take O(n log n) time, which is worse than the time complexity of a hash table.